# How to show a User view in GWT app by typing in browser address bar

Tags: gwt

I have this gwt app which say, runs on http://mygwtapp.com/ (which is actually: http://mygwtapp.com/index.html)

The app host a database of users, queried by searching usernames using the search view and results are shown in the user results view. Pretty useful enough. However I need to bb add a way that user view can be viewed by just typing http://myapp.com/user123

I am thinking that the question I have here, the answer is a server side solution. However if there's a client side solution, please let me know.

One fellow here in StackOVerflow suggested that the format would be like this:
mygwtapp.com/index.html#user123

However the format is important to be like: http://myapp.com/user123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'something' in  'http://host/path#something' is a [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). FIs have a specific feature: the page isn't reloaded if only FI part in URL changes, but they still take part in browser history.

FI's are a browser mechanism that GWT uses to create "pages", i.e. parts of GWT application that are bookmarkable and have history support.

You can try to use an URL without # (the FI separator), but then you will have a normal URL, that reloads the page with every change and it could not be (easily) a part of a normal GWT app.

Comment: yes I have tried FI, however what I have done is to a add a code inside the ValueChangeHandler which updates the model based on the event.getValue (which is the string typed, say #user123) then finally switch to the user view, this works when the app is running in hosted/debug mode, however does not work when bookmarked and reloaded in the browser, when deployed as tomcat webapp. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong without seeing the code. Do you call `History.fireCurrentHistoryState()` after you registered your history handler?

Comment: Please check this link to see how I implemented the code somehow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144038/gwt-fragment-identifier-works-in-hosted-mode-and-not-in-compiled-mode-tomcat

Comment: When you are registering history handlers the history event has already happened. You need to "re-fire" the event again after the handler is registered. Try adding `History.fireCurrentHistoryState()` after your `History.addValueChangeHandler(..)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925228/what-is-need-history-firecurrenthistorystate-in-gwt-history/6926545#6926545

Answer (score 1):

mygwtapp.com/index.html#user123
That would be using the History mechanism (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) which I would add is the recommended way of doing it.

However, if you insist on using something like  http://myapp.com/user123, one of the possible ways is to have a servlet which accepts this request (you might have to switch to something like http://myapp.com/details?id=user123). The servlet will look up the DB and return your host html back. Before returning it will inject the required details as a Dictionary entry in the page (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) On the client you can read this data and display on the UI

Comment: I assume with this solution after the servlet the browser url will show http://myapp.com/details?id=user123 and not http://myapp.com/user123