# GWT Fragment Identifier works in hosted mode and not in compiled mode (Tomcat)

Tags: gwt

I have this code below which works when running in hosted/debug mode however it does not work when deployed in Tomcat.

```
History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
                // call update model, and eventually app will show the appropriate view...

            }
        });
```

I code above responsibility is to catch the event when user type something like this in the browser:

http://http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#user123

Works well in hosted mode, but when deployed in Tomcat and accessed via the browser:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html#user123

it shows blank page.

**EDIT: Unless gwt app is first loaded and typing FI works.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this: [What is need History.fireCurrentHistoryState() in GWT History?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925228/what-is-need-history-firecurrenthistorystate-in-gwt-history/6926545#6926545)

When you load http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html#user123 for the first time, you registered your history handler after the history event has already happened. If you reload the page then it will fire.

You need to call `History.fireCurrentHistoryState()` after you registered the history handler to "re-fire" the event.

Comment: I am assuming that this would mean that my approach is far from being bookmark-able?